# Nested Hash interpreted as an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'm using a hash to store a little data needed to parse a website including URL and the specific instructions to use Nokogiri to parse the headlines of the site. However the nested Hash I used is interpreted as an Array.

```
webSite = {  :everdoH =>  
                        { :url => "http://www.everardoherrera.com/" ,
                          :instruc=> Proc.new PageToParse.css('.contentheading').css('.contentpagetitle')} 
           }
```

If I do:

```
puts webSite.class
webSite.each {|aSite| puts aSite.class }
```

The I get this:

```
>> Hash
>> Array
```

Therefore I can't use any of the Hash indexing properties.

Any idea why I am not getting class type Hash on the nested part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), [`Hash#each_pair`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair) passes key-value pair (array) as parameters.

```
webSite = {  :everdoH =>
  { :url => "http://www.everardoherrera.com/" ,
    :instruc=> 'blah'
  }
}
webSite.each { |aSite| p aSite }
# => [:everdoH, {:url=>"http://www.everardoherrera.com/", :instruc=>"blah"}]
```

Try one of followings (printing class of value, not key-value pair):

```
webSite.each {|aSite| puts aSite[1].class }
# => Hash
webSite.each {|key, aSite| puts aSite.class }
# => Hash
webSite.each_value {|aSite| puts aSite.class }
# => Hash
```

Comment: webSite.each_value {|aSite| puts aSite.class } had the best results for me. It's now recognised as a Hash and now I can use the key-value to access the nested Hash data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each_pair` to iterate

```
1.9.3p448 :060 >   webSite.each_pair{|x,y| p y.class}
Hash
 => {:everdoH=>{:url=>"http://www.everardoherrera.com/", :instruc=>"asd"}} 
1.9.3p448 :061 > 
1.9.3p448 :062 >   webSite.each_pair{|x,y| p y}
{:url=>"http://www.everardoherrera.com/", :instruc=>"asd"}
 => {:everdoH=>{:url=>"http://www.everardoherrera.com/", :instruc=>"asd"}} 
1.9.3p448 :063 > 
1.9.3p448 :064 >   webSite.each_pair{|x,y| p x}
:everdoH
 => {:everdoH=>{:url=>"http://www.everardoherrera.com/", :instruc=>"asd"}} 
1.9.3p448 :065 >
```